# Need help to prove that Image of a linear map $l\colon\mathbb{P}^m_k\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^k_n$ is closed.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I  study the book " Algebraic GeometryPart I: Schemes. With Examples and Exercises by Görtz, Wedhorn. "
 In order to give an example of a sublinear space of the projective space, they assum
that $$l\colon\mathbb{P}^m_k\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^k_n$$ be the continuous map indiuced by the injective linear transformation $$\phi\colon k^{m+1}\rightarrow k^{n+1}$$ that maps $v$ to $A[v]$ where $A$ is the matrix accosiated with the linear map $\phi$. They say that

"This is infact an ismorphism of $\mathbb{P}^k_m$ to a closed subprevariety of $\mathbb{P}^n_k$." 
So I think that one needs to prove that $\text{Im}{l}$ is closed in $\mathbb{P}^k_n$. How I can prove that it is closed?

Comment: In [this note](http://sierra.nmsu.edu/morandi/oldwebpages/Math683Fall2013/Complete.pdf) it is proved that the image of a projective variety under a morphism to another variety is closed.

Comment: Thanks! But it is still hard for me to understand  the proofs in the note. In my question $l$ is given by  some homogeneous polynomials of degree one. It is much simple than that in the general form. Do you think there is  a simple way to prove the Image in  this case is close?

Comment: Just a thought: Since $\mathbb P_k^n$ has a finite affine open covering $D_+(T_i)$, it suffices to show that the intersection of the image with each $D_+(T_i)$ is closed. This corresponds to a morphism $\ell^{-1}(D_+(T_i)) \rightarrow D_+(T_i)$. Again cover $\ell^{-1}(D_+(T_i))$ by finitely many affine opens, this is reduced to affine mappings $k^n \rightarrow A$ for some rings $A$. I guess if we work out the details then the closedness might be clear? I am not very sure though.